# Use external input library with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How can I call functions in Kivy, such as getting audio input using `speech_recognition` from the user whilst following best practices?

I tried this approach below *(`button2` calls the `getAudioInput` function)*, this works if I allow the function to accept arbitrary arguments.
It also occasionally freezes with a loading icon when i click on the button, not to mention the function is nested in the same launch class - these all feel like signs i'm doing it wrong.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window

class SayHello(App):


    def build(self):
        Window.borderless = True
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols =1
        
        #
        #---nonrelevant code stripped out
        #


        # Button 2
        self.button2 = Button(text="talk", size_hint=(None, None))
        self.button2.bind(on_press =self.getAudioInput)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button2)



        return self.window

    def getAudioInput(*argv):

        import speech_recognition as sr

        # Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)

        r = sr.Recognizer()

        # Reading Microphone as source
        # listening the speech and store in audio_text variable

        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio_text = r.listen(source)

            # recognise throws error if unavailable 
            try:
                # using google speech recognition
                audio_text = str(r.recognize_google(audio_text))
                print(audio_text)
            except:
                 print("Sorry, I didn't get that ")
        return(audio_text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SayHello().run()
```

Comment: try `on_release=lambda *args: Thread(target=self.getAudioInput).start()`

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of freezing problematics in my applications in the beggining. I learned by experimentation that it's better to create everything first and then call it rather than create when you need it.

- `import speech_recognition as sr` shouldn't be on the button click event but on the app's creation.
- more questionnable but you could do the same for `r = sr.Recognizer()` (I would)

if you try the listener without kivy, you gonna see that `r.recognize_google(audio_text)` is a function that takes time so it's not about kivy speed.
Actually, kivy will wait that this long function finish before doing anything else so you could try a little thread. Without touching the ui, threading is not too hard in kivy.